# "Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window" After Upgrade Xcode

Tags: uipopovercontroller, xcode4.4

I have a project using Xcode4.3, but then I upgrade Xcode to 4.4.1, and the errors came out. My app does not have any error, and now I have some errors at runtime. 
The first of them is "Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window"
I have a MainViewController, and this ViewController calls another ViewController, with a Popover. When I want to turn back to my MainViewController, my app crashes. This is my code:

```
-(void)clearAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
   if(self.popover &&self.popover.popoverVisible){
      [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:animated];
   }
}
```

So, after some research, I've found the solution was this:

```
-(void)clearAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
   if(self.popover &&self.popover.popoverVisible){
      if (self.view.window != nil)
         [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:animated];
   }
}
```

And kind of works, because now my app doesn't crash, but now in MainViewController, the place where the popover was, it is like a shadow, like the popover is still there.

Then, when I try to go to my SecondViewController, the error appears... 
How can dismiss popover?